# Writing to flume using spool directory how to rename file

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng

I am writing to hdfs using flume spool directory. Here is my code

```
 #initialize agent's source, channel and sink
agent.sources = test
agent.channels = memoryChannel
agent.sinks = flumeHDFS

# Setting the source to spool directory where the file exists
agent.sources.test.type = spooldir
agent.sources.test.spoolDir = /johir
agent.sources.test.fileHeader = false
agent.sources.test.fileSuffix = .COMPLETED

# Setting the channel to memory
agent.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory
# Max number of events stored in the memory channel
agent.channels.memoryChannel.capacity = 10000
# agent.channels.memoryChannel.batchSize = 15000
agent.channels.memoryChannel.transactioncapacity = 1000000

# Setting the sink to HDFS
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.path =/user/root/
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream

# Write format can be text or writable
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text

# use a single csv file at a time
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.maxOpenFiles = 1

# rollover file based on maximum size of 10 MB
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.rollCount=0
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.rollInterval=0
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 1000000
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.batchSize =1000

# never rollover based on the number of events
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 0

# rollover file based on max time of 1 min
#agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
# agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.idleTimeout = 600

# Connect source and sink with channel
agent.sources.test.channels = memoryChannel
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.channel = memoryChannel
```

But he problem is data being written to the file is renamed to some a random tmp name. How can I rename the file in hdfs to my original file name in the source directory. For example I have the file day1.txt, day2.txt,day3.txt. Those are data for two different days. I want keep them stored in hdfs as day1.txt,day2.txt,day3.txt. But these three files are merged and stored in hdfs as `FlumeData.1464629158164.tmp` file. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the original file name, you should attach the filename as a header to each event.

1. Set the *basenameHeader* property to true. This will create a header with the *basename* key unless set to something else using the *basenameHeaderKey* property.
2. Use the *hdfs.filePrefix* property to set the filename using *basenameHeader* values.

Add the below properties to your configuration file.

```
#source properties
agent.sources.test.basenameHeader = true

#sink properties
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.filePrefix = %{basename}
```